# can i use from EventListeners in workers?

Tags: javascript, browser, web-worker, service-worker

I Want To Know Is It Possible That Use From `window.addEventListener('online', function(e) { console.log('online'); });` In Workers? I Need Somthing Like This That Notify Network Connection To Users.

Comment: This code will be running in the client, so you wouldn't be detecting the server's connection to the user. The user would be detecting their connection to the server.

Comment: Try it and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

Every eventListener  should have a event this wants the interface corresponds to the event..eg:if you want key to perform some action .then first of all key listener should registered with the key and if any key pressed then key event asks keylistener(interface)taking key event event as argument and performs to print  certain a msg..

Answer (score 0):

might help

```
window.navigator.onLine
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine